# Analysis of list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings of variable length, from which I should remove elements of a certain length ONLY IF all the elements don't have the same length.

e.g.:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] # should remains the same (all elements have the same lenght)
```

but:

```
my_list = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'b', 'bcd'] # 'a' and 'b' because their length is <2.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Check if all elements have the same length. 2. Delete whichever elements you want to delete.

Comment: In your case you will have to perform two loops: 1. To check the length of all elements. If it is not equal. Then 2. Delete elements of certain length.

Comment: where is the length threshold defined? Why `2` and not say `3`?

Comment: ok guys thanks a lot, i do understand how to do it but actually my problem is writing the code

Comment: There are a lot of answers, yet you don't choose one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

```
lengths = set([len(x) for x in mylist])
mylist = mylist if len(lengths) == 1
         else [x for x in mylist if len(x) != preferred_length]
```

Another solution which is suggested by @Ev.Kounis:

```
new_list = my_list if all(len(x) == len(my_list[0]) for x in my_list[1:]) else [x for x in my_list if len(x) >= preferred_length]
```

Comment: `new_list = my_list if all(len(x) == len(my_list[0]) for x in my_list[1:]) else [x for x in my_list if len(x) >= preferred_length]`

Comment: hmmm `all(len(x) == len(my_list[0]) for x in my_list[1:])` makes more sense.

Comment: storing the `len(my_list[0])` is the only improvement I can think of. Right now it is being calulated `len(my_list) - 1` times.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yeah the overhead from `my_list[0]` would be removed if it is stored. Still a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, this should do what you want, assuming your threshold can defined:

```
my_list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

my_list2 = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'b', 'bcd']

my_list3 = ['ab', 'abc', 'ac', 'defe']

def check_len(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return True

    first = lst[0]

    return all(len(x) == len(first) for x in lst[1:])

def filter_lst(lst, threshold):
    if check_len(lst):
        return lst

    return list(filter(lambda x : len(x) < threshold, lst))
    # or [x for x in lst if len(x) < 2], had this before, but decided to do something different

>>> print(filter_lst(my_list1, 2))
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print(filter_lst(my_list2, 2))
['a', 'b']
>>> print(filter_lst(my_list3, 3))
['ab', 'ac']
```

This solution follows this procedure:

- Check if all the elements are of the same length, using [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#all) for lists with length `2` or greater
- If they are all the same length, whereby `check_len()` returns `True`, return the list normally, irregardless of the `threshold`.
- Otherwise, [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) only the elements in the list that are less than `<` the `threshold` in length.

Answer (score 0):

```
def funtion(list, length):
    my_list_len = len(list)
    for i in range(my_list_len - 1):
        if len(list[i]) != len(list[i + 1]):
            for j in range(my_list_len - 1, -1, -1):
                if len(list[j]) < length:
                    list.pop(j)

            break
    return list
```

Function

```
list = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'b', 'bcd']
list2 = funtion(list, 2)
```

return

```
['ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'bcd']
```